# C# Matching a recursive structure in a string

Tags: c#, string, parsing, recursion, text-extraction

I'm currently working on a program that loads up a text file, searches through it to find a specific structure, and then replaces a certain part of that structure with different text.

The structure I need to find and extract is `"N"(N)` where N is any character. For example. Lets say I had a text file like this:

> Everyone knows the saying "Do not do more than you can do" (Jim Doe).
>   Well, I'm here to tell you that this saying is awesome. Here is
>   another, "The sky is blue and the sun is bright" (Sally Wantsmore).

I would want to be able to match the text `"Do not do more than you can do" (Jim Doe)` along with `"The sky is blue and the sun is bright" (Sally Wantsmore)`.

I don't think there is really a way to do this with a regular expression from the best of my knowledge. I've been trying for the last few days. I can't get it to work, it's a recursive pattern by nature. My question is, how would I go about writing C# code to parse through and find these patterns. I would like to do something where I can find the position within the string and the length, that way I can then extract it from the string.

EDIT
I need to be able to capture all characters in the quote. This means that there could also be another set of quotes within the quote and even another set of parenthesis. This means that the structure could also contain a match within itself.

I'm now trying to use this expression because I need to be able to capture all characters within a quote: `\"(.+)\" \(([\w ]+)\)`

The listed answers below both work. However, I've discovered a limitation. There is a possible recursive structure to this. The problem I am currently having is when there is a `"N"(N)` inside of a `"N"(N)"`. For example:

> "Random quote" (random person) Here is a fun saying, "The sky is blue and
>   the sun is bright, some even say "really bright" (others)" (Sally
>   Wantsmore).

This presents many problems. There is only one match because it takes the very first ", and then finds the last " just after (others) and finds the set of parens for (Sally Wantsmore) and only finds that match. However, I desire for it to find all the matches, especially the beginning one and last one separably, and even the inner quote. Is this possible with Regular expressions? If not, how do I go about solving this with Recursive c# code.

Comment: So you want to find a quoted string followed by the authors name in brackets?

Comment: Why can't you use regular expressions for this?

Comment: \"([\w ]+)\" \(([\w ]+)\) works well, But how do I add a check for punctuation? For instance, it won't find "Do not, do more than you can do" (Jim Doe) because of the comma.

Answer (score 3):

The following regex should find the two things you're looking for:

```
\"([\w ]+)\" \(([\w ]+)\)
```

In C# you can use Regex.Match to retrieve the two items in brackets.

Answer (score 2):

An example on how you could have it in C#:

```
var quotes = Regex.Matches(@"Everyone knows the saying ""Do not do more than you can do"" (Jim Doe). Well, I'm here to tell you that this saying is awesome. Here is another, ""The sky is blue and the sun is bright"" (Sally Wantsmore).", 
    "(?<Quotes>\"(?<Text>[\\w ]+)\\\" \\((?<Author>[\\w ]+)\\))", RegexOptions.Singleline);

foreach (Match quote in quotes)
{
    var text = quote.Groups["Text"].Value;
    var author = quote.Groups["Author"].Value;
    Console.WriteLine($"Text: {text}, Author: {author}");
}
```

Comment: Are the <Quotes> and <Text> and <Author> tags a regular expression syntax or is this c# regex only. When I run "(?<Quotes>\"(?<Text>[\\w ]+)\\\" \\((?<Author>[\\w ]+)\\))" at regexr.com, it doesn't seem to find any matches.

Comment: Those are names for groups. Not aware of other regex flavors with those. It's a .NET  thing

Comment: Cool, I'll give it a try in visual studio. That would be nice for it to work this way.

Comment: Ya just go it running in a console program. It's working like a beauty.

Comment: Great! If you find an answer that solves your problem. Considering Marking it accepted: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work